# How do I clone a single part of content from a h3-element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning everybody!

I hope you can help me simplifying my code-snippet.
I'm cloning a h3-element with all its content.
This cloned element contains two a-elements and three different text snippets.
I want to remove the a-elements and part1 and part2 of the content being some static text.
They only text I want to hold is textOfUnknownLength.

**Problem 1** I have to use the jQuery-library from version 2.6.
This is my code I got so far and it's ugly. I just couldn't figure out another way.

The cloned h3-element

```
<h3 class="title">
   part1 <a href="#" class="link1">text</a>
   part2 textOfUnknownLength
   <a href="#" class="link2">text</a>
</h3>
```

My code to get the textOfUnknownLength

```
var name = $("h3",e).clone();
name.find(".link1, .link2").remove();
name.filter("h3").each(function(){
  if($(this).html() != ''){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('part1','').replace('part2',''));
  }
});
```

**Problem 2** I want to replace h3 with span, but hold the content. How would I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you're able to change the format I would wrap the "part1", "part2" etc in spans. Otherwise you will need to split the string which could get messy.

Comment: Hi, I'm alreday splitting it. The problem is to replace the h3-element with a span-element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bZ8px/1

```
var name = $('.title').text().split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name[i] == 'part2')
        $('.title').after('<span>'+name[i+1]+'</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace all `h3`s with `span`s you could use this:

```
$( "h3" ).each( function( index, element ) {
   var $element = $( element );
   $element.replaceWith( "<span>" + $element.html() + "</span>" );
} );
```

**EDIT:** I edited the code to work with your jQuery Version (< 1.4)

**EDIT 2:** I edited the code to REALLY work with your jQuery Version (< 1.4)

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer. Somehow the content disapperas. I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eHtjn/ . Could you give me an example of how to implement it in my code?

Comment: Ok, seems the jquery-version you're using doesn't support providing initial properties to a newly created element yet. Missed that ...

Comment: I updated the code. Seems to work fine in the fiddle you provided

Comment: Hm, you're right. But the solution is simple: Just write `$element.replaceWith( "<span>" + $element.html() + "</span>" );` According to http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ this should work in jQuery 1.2

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to turn

```
<h3 class="title">
   part1 <a href="#" class="link1">text</a>
   part2 textOfUnknownLength
   <a href="#" class="link2">text</a>
</h3>
```

into

```
<span>textOfUnknownLength</span>
```

Check out:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6DKe/8/